# Add a clip_analysis to a buffer_analysis

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a clip_analysis to the buffer_analysis I just completed.

The script that I'm using is:

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(sites[i]+'.shp', sites[i]+'_Buffer3000.shp','3000')
print 'site buffered to',i,'buffer 3000'
arcpy.Clip_analysis(openSpace,[i]+'.shp', [i]+'_OpenSpace.shp')
print 'open space clipped to',i,'city limits'
```

When I leave the script like this, I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

or a error that says unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis(openSpace,[i]+'.shp', [i]+'_OpenSpace.shp')
```

you're trying to append together the list `[i]` to the string `.shp`

...did you mean to write:

```
arcpy.Clip_analysis(openSpace,sites[i]+'.shp', [i]+'_OpenSpace.shp')
```